# What should I do to change the admin form for a model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an admin form for a model which looks like this:

```
[Label:Class]   [Select_Widget:("A" or "B")]
[Label:Objects] [Select_Widget:empty by default]

...
```

A & B are both Models in my db.

What would I need to do so that when I select either "A" or "B" from the first select, the second gets populated automatically with all the objects from that class? Where would I override? And what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this via jQuery ( AJAX ) and exposing the models as JSON.